# Homeomorphism, compactification

Tags: general-topology

Let $\hat{X}$ be a compactification of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$.

Show, that it exists an unique, continuous function $p_{\hat{X}}:\hat{X}\to X^+$, whose restriction on $X$ is the identity. (This taks is already done here: [Compactification, definite function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781998/compactification-definite-function?noredirect=1#comment3637608_1781998))

Show, that if $\hat{X}\setminus X$ contains just one element, than $p_{\hat{X}}$ is a homeomorphism.

Therefore I have to show, that $p_{\hat{X}}$ is a bijection and $p_{\hat{X}}$ and $p^{-1}_{\hat{X}}$ is continuous.

I already know, that $p_{\hat{X}}$ is continuous. So we have to prove, that this function is a bijection and the inverse function is also continuous.

$p_{\hat{X}}(x)=\begin{cases}x\quad\text{for}\,\, x\in X\\\infty\quad\text{else}\end{cases}$

Is obviously a bijection. $\hat{X}\setminus X=\{x'\}$ and $x'\notin X$.
Hence $p_{\hat{X}}(x')=\infty$ and for every $x\in X$ is $p_{\hat{X}}$ the identity of $X$. 
Therefore a bijection.

Next I have to give the inverse function, which should be easy too:

$p^{-1}_{\hat{X}}: X^+\to \hat{X}$ with

$p^{-1}_{\hat{X}}(x)=\begin{cases}x'\quad\text{for}\,\, x=\infty \\ x\quad\text{else}\end{cases}$

Are my thoughts correct?

Now I have to show, that the preimage of an open set, is open.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in this case more convenient to use closed sets than open sets.

Comment: A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomomorphism.

Comment: Yes, I know, but is the compactification of a locally compact Hausdorff-space Hausdorff?

Comment: @MrTopology yes, a compactification (at least for completely regular spaces) is required to be Hausdorff by definition. And the codomain is $X^+$ which I presume you already know is Hausdorff.